# What do the options "full chroma interpolation" and "full chroma input" do in video scaling? [ffmpeg]

Tags: ffmpeg

In ffmpeg, there are options `full_chroma_int` and `full_chroma_inp` that can be passed to the video scaling filter. These options are sometimes present in command line examples for the resizing filter, such as in [FFmpeg Wiki: Scaling](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling).

The documentation just describes these options as "Enable full chroma interpolation." and "Select full chroma input." respectively. However, it is not clear to me what these options are for and how they affect quality or encoding time.

Does anyone have an intuitive explanation and/or a rule of thumb when to use these options?

Comment: I'm guessing that full chroma interpolation means no chroma subsampling, i.e. use yuv444 rather than yuv420 etc.